# Using '|' (pipe) operator with std::views does not compile

Tags: c++, std, c++20

After a career diversion, I am trying to get up to speed with std::views (and functional programming in general). I am using the '|' (pipe) operator with std::views::filter on a vector, and I am puzzled why some code structures compile and others don't.

This code creates a vector of vectors of `int`, then filters them by sum. I've commented the three statements that are confusing me, the first two of which compile and the third doesn't.

Compilation error is:

```
'|': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::vector<std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>,std::allocator<std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

(Using MSVC19, compiled with `/std:c++latest`)

I am puzzled as to why this doesn't compile while (2) especially does?

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <ranges>

template<typename T>
auto buildMultiples(const std::vector<T>& base)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> vRet;
    for(T n= 1; n <= 5; n++)
    {
        auto v = base;
        for (auto& m : v) m *= n;
        vRet.push_back(v);
    }
    return vRet;
}

template<typename T>
struct sumGreaterThan
{
    T _limit{ 0 };

    auto operator()(const std::vector<T>& v) {return std::accumulate(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), 0) > _limit;}
};
   
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    vector<int> nums{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    auto mults = buildMultiples(nums);

    for (auto& m : buildMultiples(nums)) {} //1. Compiles

    sumGreaterThan sumFilter{ 10 };
    
    auto vecs = buildMultiples(nums);
    for (auto& m : vecs | views::filter(sumFilter)) {} //2. Compiles

    for (auto& m : buildMultiples(nums) | views::filter(sumFilter)) {} //3. Compilation Error!!

    for (auto vecs = buildMultiples(nums); auto & m : vecs | views::filter(sumFilter)) {} // 4. Compiles. Thanks @Aryter
}
```

Comment: What if you use `const auto&`?

Comment: You can also do `for (auto vecs = buildMultiples(nums); auto& m : vecs | views::filter(sumFilter))` if you want

Comment: @Artyer That syntax looked weird to me (I wondered if you had mistyped a `;` for a `,`) until further research showed it only became valid in C++20. Thanks for suggesting!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is passing an lvalue `vector` into `filter`:

```cpp
vecs | views::filter(sumFilter)
```

whereas this is passing an rvalue `vector` into `filter`:

```cpp
buildMultiples(nums) | views::filter(sumFilter)
```

The current rule, which compilers implement, is that range adaptor pipelines cannot take rvalue non-view ranges (like `vector`, `string`, etc.). This is because the pipeline itself is non-owning (views were non-owning), and exists as a safety mechanism to prevent dangling.

The new rule, recently adopted as a defect, would allow this could and would cause `filter` to *own* the result of `buildMultiples` (this is [P2415](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2415r2.html)), but compilers don't implement it quite yet. With this change, your other version would also have compiled.

So for now, you will have to keep writing it this way (as you are already doing):

```cpp
auto vecs = buildMultiples(nums);
for (auto& m : vecs | views::filter(sumFilter)) { ... }
```

Comment: I suspected it was an R-value, L-value thing, but I thought the result of `buildMultiples()` would be valid for the duration of the loop, as it is in version (1). The wording of the error description was a bit confusing too as version(2) seemed to be supplying the same lhs parameter type). Thank you for the clear explanation, and the update on the language evolution.

Comment: @DS_London It would not have been if it were simply captured by reference - not all expressions in the range-based for initializer have their lifetime extended. Without the view actually _owning_ the result of `buildMultiples`, your choice is either (a) don't compile or (b) have a dangling reference. Given that choice, I'd prefer (a). Although I even more strongly prefer option (c): just make it do the right thing. Which is what we did :-)

Comment: @DS_London To make it more confusing. `ranges::for_each(buildMultiplies(~) | views::filter(~), [&](auto& m){ ... })` would have actually been just fine - it's specifically the range-based for that would unconditionally dangle :-(